# Maven scala scoverage try to pull package for other module

Tags: scala, maven, code-coverage

I have a multimodule maven project with the following schema

```
root

 - module-A
 - module-B (depends on A)
 - module-C1 (depends on B)
 - module-C2 (depends on B)
 ...
 - module-Cn (depends on B)
```

And it has the scoverage-maven-plugin configured like this.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
    <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${scoverage.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

scoverage.plugin.version = 1.4.1
scala.version = 2.11.11

If I lunch a `mvn clean package` in local from the root project, it works as expected, but in the CI workflow (bamboo if its useful), modules A and B go great, but on C1 I get the following error:

```
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] >>> scoverage-maven-plugin:1.4.1:report (report) > [scoverage]test @ C1 >>>
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] 
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] --- scoverage-maven-plugin:1.4.1:pre-compile (report) @ C1 ---
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] Downloading from nexus: https://fakenexusurl.com/repository/all/module-B/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] Downloading from nexus: https://fakenexusurl.com/repository/all/module-B/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/module-B-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] 
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] root .......................................... SUCCESS [  3.610 s]
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] module-A ................................... SUCCESS [01:38 min]
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] modulde-B ............................. SUCCESS [01:30 min]
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] module-C1 ........................... FAILURE [01:37 min]
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] module-C2 ........................... SKIPPED
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] Total time: 04:50 min
14-May-2020 14:23:41    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-14T14:23:41Z
14-May-2020 14:23:42    [INFO] Final Memory: 85M/1627M
14-May-2020 14:23:42    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-May-2020 14:23:42    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project module-C1: Could not resolve dependencies for project group:module-C1:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact group:module-B:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in nexus (https://fakenexusurl.com/repository/all/) -> [Help 1]
```

I see that it's trying to download module B from the nexus of the company, and of course, it's not there because we didn't publish this snapshot. But I don't understand why it's trying to download dependencies that should look in another module of the same project. And why it doesn't do the same for B that depends on A, if the file are equal except the module name and the dependencies.

All the dependencies used are declared in the root `dependencyManagment`, and the plugins in the `pluginManagment`

The CI workflow is a black box for us, we can't know if they are using any extra profiles. The only thing we know is that the launch `mvn clean package` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow of scoverage creates a fork of the maven flow, and reruns all until testing. In this fork is not well managed the dependencies between modules, so the only way to execute it correctly from a clean execution is with the command:

```
mvn clean install scoverage:report
```

Change install to package, deploy, or any element that needs the report. This will force maven to execute the `scoverage:report` at the end of each module, preventing the unwanted behaviour.

Foud the information in [this thread](https://github.com/scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin/issues/51).